# JSF/ADF selectOneChoice shortDesc size

Tags: oracle, jsf, oracle-adf, jspx

I have created a selectOneChoice with a property binding.

```
<af:selectOneChoice
        simple="true"
        binding="#{backing_Deletion.nodeRenderer.propBinding['value']}"
        contentStyle="width:500px;"/>
```

The `nodeRenderer` is providing a shortDesc from an Oracle DRM server. The problem is that when rendered the `shortDesc` is only 8 characters wide and 70 lines in height.

Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Found a little more information. The propBinding is a map, which contained the shortDesc attribute. The shortDesc attribute is a String. The problem I was having was due to the width of the panel the selectOneChoice was located in. I still do not know a way to specifically affect the shortDesc, but I have found a work around, in making the selectOneChoice smaller in width than the panel it was located in.

Answer (score 0):

The length of this attribute would have to be in the model layer. If it is specified there as part of the hints that the maximum length of the LOV is 8 then it would not display more that that. You could get the precision from the model with something like :

```
#{bindings.sampleAttribute.hints.precision}
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove contentStyle="width:500px; and
Add "AFStretchWidth" style class

Comment: is that valid for all ADF versions?